# Script/Design toggle button in polymer designer malfunction

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I am experiencing a weird behavior of the polymer designer tool. When I click on the code/designer toggle button it switches to the code. Then when I switch back to the design it is gone. The Tree also only shows the default my-element element. Am I the only one who is experiencing such behavior? Is there a solution?

PS: I'm using chrome.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you reported the issue on github?

Comment: Turns out somebody reported it 4 days ago. https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues/61. I hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't wait for the fix on the Polymer site, then you can clone the designer code from GitHub https://github.com/Polymer/designer and you'll find that the bug doesn't exist in that code.